# Homotopy type of $X\times S^1/x_0\times S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

The reduced suspension of X is defined as
$$
\Sigma X=S^1\times X/S^1\vee X
$$
I'm wondering what will happen if I only shrink one $S^1$ to a point.

In which condition can I have $S^1\times X/S^1\times x_0\simeq X\vee \Sigma X$?

Thanks.

Comment: $\Sigma X\cong S^1\wedge X$ @cherrycoke2000

Comment: You're saying $S^1\times X/1\times X$, right? @BalarkaSen

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. You are correct, I misread the question.